# Python - code works, but I don't know why

Tags: python-3.4

Basically I want someone to give me a simple rundown of how this bit of python code works. Much appreciated

vari :

```
kw1 = ['keyword1', 'keyword2']

problem = input("Detect keywords from list\n")
```

main :

```
if set(kw1).intersection(problem.split()):

print(" Kw found. ")

else:

print(" Keywords not found. ")
```

Comment: I just needed a straight explanation, I adapted some code and wanted to make sure I know why it works, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of things there.

First, when you call `input` you're asking for the user to give you an input string.

When you use `split()` on it you transform it into a list of strings, by separating the input string based on the empty spaces, so that `"bla bli blo".split()` gives you `["bla","bli","blo"]`.

Then, when you call `set(my_list)`, it will transform `my_list` into a **set**, which is a mathematical construct without any duplicates and which responds to operators like **union**, **intersection** and so on.

Finally, when you compare your set (made from splitting the user input) to a list of keywords, if there are no matches (so none of the keywords in the list appreared directly in the user input), then it will give you an empty set and that will be considered as **false** by the `if`. So `if set(["bla","bli","blo"]).intersection(["blu"])` will not activate, but `if set(["bla","bli","blo"]).intersection(["blu","blo"])` will, as it is not an empty set.

Note that if you want to recognize keywords inside words, this method will NOT work. For instance, if you're looking for keywords `kw1=['car','truck','bike']` and the user inputs `cars trucks bikes`, none of the keywords will be recognized, because the `split()` will split along empty spaces, giving you `['cars','trucks','bikes']` and `'cars'!='car'`...

Comment: Thank you, very detailed answer and I credit you for this.

Comment: Thank you. If my answer is enough for you, would you mind accepting it? And if it is somehow lacking, would you mind telling me how to improve it?

Comment: Oh yes of course, I apologise, I literally just made an account here so I'm new to everything.

Comment: Don't worry, I'm quite new as well. Was a lurker for years, but only today decided to contribute. I'm trying to be helpful ;)

Comment: Haha, on the same page then, thanks for the help as always

Comment: You are very welcome and I wish you all the best. :D